# Rails 4 - Check if user click "No" when prompted using data-confirm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Ajax Delete button using Jquery UJS

```
<%= link_to "Delete Product", @product, method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: "You can't undo this. Are you sure?",
              remote: true } %>
```

When user clicked the link, it will add `is-loading` class in it

```
$("a[data-remote='true']").on("click", function(){
  $(this).addClass("is-loading");
});
```

When success, it will remove the products.

The problem is, when the user click **No** in the prompt (caused by `data-confirm`), the `.is-loading` class is already applied.

Is there any callback to check what user choose on `data-confirm`?

Thanks

[EDIT]

**ANSWERS** by ryaz

So ryaz's answer is correct, but too short. So for other's reference, here's my code after applying his answer:

```
$("a[data-remote='true']").on("ajax:beforeSend", function(){
  $(this).addClass("is-loading");
});
```

This will add `is-loading` class if AJAX event started, so if the user click **No**, it won't add the loading class.

Comment: You should remove 'is-loading' class when ajax completed ;)

Comment: @ryaz Yep, of course I didn't forget to remove the class. I just didn't include it here because it's not relevant for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ajax:beforeSend` and `ajax:complete` event hooks.